# Python + Requests + Eve : Sending data to post fails with error code 422

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, eve

I just bumped into somewhat strange behavior while doing my RESTful Eve project

For this step i have to add some data to eve's db.

I wanted to use python's requests module to make a POST with data I have to save

Here is what I'm sending (`author` is a variable that contains some data):

```
data = {"author_id": author.author_id,
        "orcid": author.orcid,
        "hindex": author.hindex,
        "ndocuments": author.hindex,
        "ncited_by": author.ncited_by,
        "citation_count": author.citation_count,
        "current_affiliation": author.affiliation_history[0].affiliation_id,
        "affiliation_history": [x.affiliation_id for x in author.affiliation_history],
        "subject_areas": [{"name": x[0], "frequency": x[1]} for x in author.subject_areas],
        "publication_history": [{"title": x[0], "issn": x[3]} for x in author.publication_history],
        "firstname": author.firstname,
        "lastname": author.lastname}

r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/professors', data=data)
return r.status_code
```

Which returns 422.
I have printed to console what `data` contains before sending and looks like this

```
    {
   "author_id":"57190708172",
   "orcid":"",
   "hindex":"1",
   "ndocuments":"1",
   "ncited_by":"18",
   "citation_count":"18",
   "current_affiliation":"104571568",
   "affiliation_history":[
      "104571568",
      "60022084",
      "116039394",
      "100252088"
   ],
   "subject_areas":[
      {
         "name":"Biomaterials",
         "frequency":"4"
      },
      {
         "name":"Biomedical Engineering",
         "frequency":"4"
      }
   ],
   "publication_history":[
      {
         "title":"Czechoslovak Medicine",
         "issn":"01399179"
      },
      {
         "title":"Ceskoslovenska Patologie",
         "issn":"00090611"
      }
   ],
   "firstname":"Albert Vlastimil",
   "lastname":"V\u00e1lek"
}
```

It looks fine and has all data from `author`. Now here is the problem which I cannot understand.
Sending the request with `requests.post(...)` always fails with code `422 - Unprocessable Entity` BUT coping the output from above and sending it with a REST client works perfectly (`code 201 - Created`)

Here is also a video https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SwslPKMv0hn1CN8rDnOk7YrTjpr-4OZO

Comment: What's in the response body? There must be an explanation there.

Comment: Here is the response which looks like something screwed up: https://pastebin.com/CKx0kJ4w

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to make the requests call setting the body as `json`, like this:

```
requests.post('http://localhost:5000/professors', json=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem, the solution was setting header's content type, sending the data as json

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/affiliation', data=j, headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'})
```

Where

```
j = json.dumps(data)
```